# How do I search for a keyword in all_mviews script?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, materialized-views

I am trying to search for the keyword `CUSTOMER` in the script used to create a materialisd view. I am doing this by searching the `QUERY` column of the table `all_mviews`. So in theory the statement

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_MVIEWS
WHERE UPPER(QUERY) LIKE '%CUSTOMER%';
```

Should work. However, because query is not a CHAR datatype I cannot do this. I have tried using `TO_CHAR(QUERY)`, `DMBS_LOB.INSTR(QUERY, 'CUSTOMER')`, `TO_LOB(QUERY)`. Nothing seems to work. Ideally I want to do this in plain SQL not PL/SQL.

Comment: I can't edit my post, but the `QUERY` datatype is a LONG

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly query in plain SQL, but you will not be able to get away from using PL/SQL under the covers. That's because LONGs can only be manipulated by PL/SQL.

To accomplish this, you have to write a PL/SQL function that wraps around the dictionary view in question (here `all_mviews`), translates the `LONG` datatype to a `CLOB`, and emits the replacement rows. You can then query that function with a pure SQL query and apply search predicates to it like normal. Here's a version that is intended for the columns available in 19c:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_mviews_rectype IS OBJECT (
        CONTAINER_NAME  VARCHAR2(128),
        QUERY   CLOB,
        QUERY_LEN   NUMBER,
        UPDATABLE   VARCHAR2(1),
        UPDATE_LOG  VARCHAR2(128),
        MASTER_ROLLBACK_SEG VARCHAR2(128),
        MASTER_LINK VARCHAR2(128),
        REWRITE_ENABLED VARCHAR2(1),
        REWRITE_CAPABILITY  VARCHAR2(9),
        REFRESH_MODE    VARCHAR2(9),
        REFRESH_METHOD  VARCHAR2(8),
        BUILD_MODE  VARCHAR2(9),
        FAST_REFRESHABLE    VARCHAR2(18),
        LAST_REFRESH_TYPE   VARCHAR2(8),
        LAST_REFRESH_DATE   DATE,
        LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME   DATE,
        STALENESS   VARCHAR2(19),
        AFTER_FAST_REFRESH  VARCHAR2(19),
        UNKNOWN_PREBUILT    VARCHAR2(1),
        UNKNOWN_PLSQL_FUNC  VARCHAR2(1),
        UNKNOWN_EXTERNAL_TABLE  VARCHAR2(1),
        UNKNOWN_CONSIDER_FRESH  VARCHAR2(1),
        UNKNOWN_IMPORT  VARCHAR2(1),
        UNKNOWN_TRUSTED_FD  VARCHAR2(1),
        COMPILE_STATE   VARCHAR2(19),
        USE_NO_INDEX    VARCHAR2(1),
        STALE_SINCE DATE,
        NUM_PCT_TABLES  NUMBER,
        NUM_FRESH_PCT_REGIONS   NUMBER,
        NUM_STALE_PCT_REGIONS   NUMBER,
        SEGMENT_CREATED VARCHAR2(3),
        EVALUATION_EDITION  VARCHAR2(128),
        UNUSABLE_BEFORE VARCHAR2(128),
        UNUSABLE_BEGINNING  VARCHAR2(128),
        DEFAULT_COLLATION   VARCHAR2(100),
        ON_QUERY_COMPUTATION    VARCHAR2(1)
        )
        /
        CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_mviews_tabtype IS TABLE OF dba_mviews_rectype
        /
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dba_mviews_ext (in_owner IN varchar2, in_mview_name IN varchar2)
          RETURN dba_mviews_tabtype PIPELINED
        AS  
          var_cursor binary_integer;
          var_query varchar2(4000);
          res pls_integer;
          tab_desc dbms_sql.desc_tab;
          var_column_count pls_integer;
          rec_dummy_mview dba_mviews_rectype;
          var_owner dba_mviews.owner%TYPE;
          var_mview_name dba_mviews.mview_name%TYPE;
        BEGIN
          var_query := 'SELECT *
                          FROM dba_mviews
                         WHERE owner = :owner
                           AND mview_name = :mview_name';
                           
          var_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
          dbms_sql.parse(var_cursor,var_query,dbms_sql.native);
          dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'owner',in_owner);
          dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'mview_name',in_mview_name);
          
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,1,var_owner,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,2,var_mview_name,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,3,rec_dummy_mview.container_name,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column_long(var_cursor,4);

          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,5,rec_dummy_mview.query_len);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,6,rec_dummy_mview.updatable,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,7,rec_dummy_mview.update_log,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,8,rec_dummy_mview.master_rollback_seg,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,9,rec_dummy_mview.master_link,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,10,rec_dummy_mview.rewrite_enabled,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,11,rec_dummy_mview.rewrite_capability,9);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,12,rec_dummy_mview.refresh_mode,9);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,13,rec_dummy_mview.refresh_method,8);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,14,rec_dummy_mview.build_mode,9);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,15,rec_dummy_mview.fast_refreshable,18);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,16,rec_dummy_mview.last_refresh_type,8);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,17,rec_dummy_mview.last_refresh_date);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,18,rec_dummy_mview.last_refresh_end_time);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,19,rec_dummy_mview.staleness,19);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,20,rec_dummy_mview.after_fast_refresh,19);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,21,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_prebuilt,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,22,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_plsql_func,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,23,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_external_table,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,24,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_consider_fresh,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,25,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_import,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,26,rec_dummy_mview.unknown_trusted_fd,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,27,rec_dummy_mview.compile_state,19);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,28,rec_dummy_mview.use_no_index,1);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,29,rec_dummy_mview.stale_since);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,30,rec_dummy_mview.num_pct_tables);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,31,rec_dummy_mview.num_fresh_pct_regions);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,32,rec_dummy_mview.num_stale_pct_regions);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,33,rec_dummy_mview.segment_created,3);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,34,rec_dummy_mview.evaluation_edition,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,35,rec_dummy_mview.unusable_before,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,36,rec_dummy_mview.unusable_beginning,128);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,37,rec_dummy_mview.default_collation,100);
          dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,38,rec_dummy_mview.on_query_computation,1);
          
          
          res := dbms_sql.execute(var_cursor);
          
          WHILE dbms_sql.fetch_rows(var_cursor) > 0
          LOOP
            DECLARE
              var_query_clob clob;
              var_offset pls_integer := 0;
              var_buffer_length pls_integer := 32760;
              var_value_length pls_integer := 0;
              var_long_piece long;
              rec_mview dba_mviews_rectype := dba_mviews_rectype(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            BEGIN
              dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,3,rec_mview.container_name);
                      
              dbms_lob.createtemporary(var_query_clob, false, dbms_lob.call);
                
              LOOP
                dbms_sql.column_value_long(c => var_cursor,
                                           position => 4,
                                           length => var_buffer_length,
                                           offset => var_offset,
                                           value => var_long_piece,
                                           value_length => var_value_length);
                                           
                EXIT WHEN var_value_length = 0;
                
                dbms_lob.append(var_query_clob, var_long_piece);
                var_offset := var_offset + var_value_length;
              END LOOP;
              
              rec_mview.query := var_query_clob;
              
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,5,rec_mview.query_len);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,6,rec_mview.updatable);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,7,rec_mview.update_log);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,8,rec_mview.master_rollback_seg);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,9,rec_mview.master_link);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,10,rec_mview.rewrite_enabled);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,11,rec_mview.rewrite_capability);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,12,rec_mview.refresh_mode);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,13,rec_mview.refresh_method);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,14,rec_mview.build_mode);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,15,rec_mview.fast_refreshable);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,16,rec_mview.last_refresh_type);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,17,rec_mview.last_refresh_date);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,18,rec_mview.last_refresh_end_time);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,19,rec_mview.staleness);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,20,rec_mview.after_fast_refresh);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,21,rec_mview.unknown_prebuilt);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,22,rec_mview.unknown_plsql_func);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,23,rec_mview.unknown_external_table);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,24,rec_mview.unknown_consider_fresh);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,25,rec_mview.unknown_import);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,26,rec_mview.unknown_trusted_fd);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,27,rec_mview.compile_state);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,28,rec_mview.use_no_index);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,29,rec_mview.stale_since);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,30,rec_mview.num_pct_tables);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,31,rec_mview.num_fresh_pct_regions);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,32,rec_mview.num_stale_pct_regions);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,33,rec_mview.segment_created);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,34,rec_mview.evaluation_edition);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,35,rec_mview.unusable_before);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,36,rec_mview.unusable_beginning);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,37,rec_mview.default_collation);
          dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,38,rec_mview.on_query_computation);
            
              PIPE ROW(rec_mview);
            END;
          END LOOP;

          dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
          
          RETURN;
        EXCEPTION 
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);

            IF dbms_sql.is_open(var_cursor)
            THEN
              dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
            END IF;
            
            RAISE;
        END;
        /

        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dba_mviews_ext
        AS
        SELECT v.owner,
               v.mview_name,
               x.*
          FROM dba_mviews v
               CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_mviews_ext(v.owner,v.mview_name)) x
         ORDER BY owner,mview_name
        /
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_mviews_ext
        AS
        SELECT v.owner,
               v.mview_name,
               x.*
          FROM all_mviews v
               CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_mviews_ext(v.owner,v.mview_name)) x
         ORDER BY owner,mview_name
        /
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_mviews_ext
        AS
        SELECT USER owner,
               v.mview_name,
               x.*
          FROM user_mviews v
               CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_mviews_ext(USER,v.mview_name)) x
         ORDER BY mview_name
        /

        GRANT select ON DBA_MVIEWS_EXT TO select_catalog_role;
        GRANT select ON ALL_MVIEWS_EXT TO public;
        GRANT select ON USER_MVIEWS_EXT TO public;
        CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM DBA_MVIEWS_EXT FOR DBA_MVIEWS_EXT;
        CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM ALL_MVIEWS_EXT FOR ALL_MVIEWS_EXT;
        CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM USER_MVIEWS_EXT FOR USER_MVIEWS_EXT;
```

Now you can simply query using regular SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_mviews_ext
 WHERE UPPER(query) LIKE '%CUSTOMER%'
```

The same technique can be used for `dba_views`. For other much shorter `LONG`s that never exceed 4KB like you find in `dba_tab_partitions/subpartitions`, `dba_tab_columns`, `dba_ind_expressions`, etc.. you can simplify by converting the `LONG` to a `varchar2(4000)` which can be done by simple PL/SQL variable assignment, and therefore won't require `dbms_sql`. That code is much shorter, but the same principle applies: use PL/SQL to convert to a searchable datatype and use a replacement view that wraps that function.

Answer (score 0):

[`LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F) datatype has a lot of restrictions when used in SQL, so you cannot apply any function directly to `LONG` or use any predicate except null testing (though *Oracle Corporation **strongly** recommends that you convert LONG columns to LOB columns* at least from [version 8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67779/ch2.htm#3463) (for 24 years) and *as soon as possible* since [version 9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm#54201) (for 21 years), but they still keep this type in data dictionary).

But it's possible to pass this datatype through XML and deserialize as `CLOB` which will allow all the SQL capabilities of `CLOB` to be exposed. You may use [`DBMS_XMLGEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html) package for this.

```
create view v_test as
select 'some text' as res
from dual
```

```
select
  v.owner,
  v.view_name,
  v.text,
  v.text_length
from all_views v
  join xmltable(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('
      select view_name, owner, text
      from all_views
      where text is not null')

    columns
      view_name varchar2(200),
      owner varchar2(200),
      text clob
  ) flt
  on v.view_name = flt.view_name
  and v.owner = flt.owner
where flt.text like '%some%text%'
```

| OWNER | VIEW_NAME | TEXT | TEXT_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIDDLE_SHCEJNRFMOROSMIQCFFB | V_TEST | select 'some text' as res from dual | 35 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sw5QUhrn)

Answer (score 0):

sys_dburigen should do the job for you.
it takes a LONG and will return a CLOB

```
select m.owner
,      m.mview_name
,      sys_dburigen( owner  , mview_name, query, 'text()').getclob() mview_query_text
from   all_mviews m
```